# visual studio timer problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hi guys have an issue with the timer basically i have the seconds variable set to 60 and when its counted down to 0 i want my SQL command to run to change the database and then for it to produce a messagebox saying ''card confiscated'' or something then once they click ok the application to stop

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (seconds < 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Option timer Expired Card Confiscated please contact your local branch");
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        sqlCommandTimer.Parameters["@cardNum"].Value = Class1.cardNumber;
        sqlCommandTimer.Parameters["@confiscated"].Value = true;
        try
        {
            sqlCommandTimer.Connection.Open();
            sqlCommandTimer.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.Exit();
            sqlCommandTimer.Connection.Close();     
        }

    }
    else
    {
        seconds--;
        listBox2.Items.Add(seconds);
    }
```

this is my SQL command

```
UPDATE       dbo.ATMCards
SET                confiscated = @confiscated
WHERE        (cardNumber = @cardNum)
```

any help on what im missing would be greatly appreciated :) thanks

edit: oh crap sorry forgot to add my problem it goes to 0 then basically continually spams the message

Comment: Any better help on what your problem is will be better :)

Comment: What is `seconds`? How is it initialized? How is the timer started? What is the actual problem? And what is a "Visual timer"?

Comment: thank you @Rawling seems my order of stuff indeed had a big impact ont he code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MessageBox.Show` stops the rest of your code being executed until the user clicks OK/Cancel/whatever, but the timer will keep on ticking and, since you are checking `seconds < 1` rather than `== 0`, producing more messageboxes, and eventual SQL calls.

Rather than

1. Show messagebox
2. Stop timer
3. Run SQL

I would suggest you

1. Stop timer
2. Run SQL
3. Show messagebox

Stopping the timer first ensures that the `seconds < 1` branch should only ever happen once (although I'd still check `== 0` instead, and possibly change your `else` to `else if (seconds > 0)`; running the SQL second ensures that, by the time the message is shown, the user's card has indeed been confiscated.