# Timer function in c# ATM simulator

Tags: c#, timer

Hi i am trying to use the timer object in c# to update my database and set the card to confiscated if it is there for more than 5 seconds. Im having a little trouble. Will post my code below

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (seconds > 5)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Card NOT removed in time: CONFISCATED");
        login.cardConfiscated(cardNumber);
        login.Visible = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

public void cardConfiscated(string number)
{
    atmCardsTableAdapter1.confiscated(number);
    atmCardsTableAdapter1.FillByNotConfiscated(boG_10033009DataSet.ATMCards);
}
```

Comment: where is `seconds` defined? is this for homework?

Comment: You should also state what trouble you have (beyond "little").

Comment: your seconds variable is not created or incremented anywhere in you're example, you're missing some code we need to help with your problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I aplogise for my ignorance, i am a new comer to c# programming. I have defined seconds as an int. private int seconds = 5;

Comment: The trouble im having is its now showing the messagebox and it is not updating the card to confiscated within the database

Comment: is `seconds` always == 5? If so, `seconds > 5` will never be true and the behaviour you describe makes perfect sense

Comment: Very funny.. but this happens earlier.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809193/visual-studio-timer-problems

Comment: I guess this is homework then

Comment: The person who posted that is indeed a classmate of mine

Comment: Maybe all classmate should build a chat room, and them we can meet there ;)

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first, you're never setting the interval on your timer.

```
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1 = new Timer(5000);  // sets interval to 5 seconds
    timer1.Elapsed += new new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

I'm doing a five second interval above, so that we don't have to call the timer more than once, when 5 seconds passes, we can just skip to the juicy stuff:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("Card NOT removed in time: CONFISCATED");
    login.cardConfiscated(cardNumber);
    login.Visible = true;
    this.Close();
}
```

Finally, you should note that if you're timer had a shorter interval, then you need to increment your seconds, for example:

```
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1 = new Timer(1000);  // sets interval to 1 second
    timer1.Elapsed += new new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.AutoReset = true;   // sets the timer to restart after each run
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Then we'd need to increment seconds each interval, like you did.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds++;
    if (seconds > 5)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Card NOT removed in time: CONFISCATED");
        login.cardConfiscated(cardNumber);
        login.Visible = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```